# rails render extract value from json response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, typhoeus

I have a Rails app and I am trying to render an array of items from a parsed JSON hash.

My current render statement looks like this

```
resp = JSON.parse(response.body)
render json: resp
```

I am using Typheous and this code did not work for me:

```
resp = JSON.parse(response.body).fetch("item")
```

The following is the JSON hash (the `item` key has many values but I'm only displaying one for brevity):

```
{
  ebay: [{
    findItemsByKeywordsResponse: [{
      ack: [],
      version: [],
      timestamp: [],
      searchResult: [{
        count: "91",
        item: [{
          itemId: [ "321453454731" ]
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }]
}
```

How can I render an array of items from the parsed JSON hash?

Comment: Are there many values for the `findItemsByKeywordsResponse` and `searchResult` keys? If so, you'll have to iterate through each of those keys to narrow down to the `item` array. For example, using the posted hash, in order to get the array of the single `item`, you'd need something like this: `resp[:ebay].first[:findItemsByKeywordsResponse].first[:searchResult].first[:item]`, which would produce `{:itemId=>["321453454731"]}`

Comment: No there is only one value of ebay and findItemsKeywordsResponse i need entire item list/array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is only one value for the `ebay` and `findItemsByKeywordsResponse` keys (per the OP's comment), you could retrieve an array of `items` by doing something like this:

```
resp = JSON.parse(response.body)
resp[:ebay].first[:findItemsByKeywordsResponse].first[:searchResult].first[:item]
```

This will give you an array of hashes containing the `itemId` and any other key-value pairs.

The reason you want to include the `.first` (or `[0]`) is because based on the parsed JSON response, your hash contains an array of hashes nested all the way to the `item` array. If there are multiple `searchResult` values, you'll need to iterate through those before getting your `item` array.

Comment: thanks the explanation was helpful. this worked for me render json: resp["findItemsByKeywordsResponse"].first["searchResult"].first["item"] and render json: resp.first["findItemsByKeywordsResponse"].first["searchResult"].first["item"] doesnt work as of now no idea why

Comment: You're welcome. If `resp.first...` doesn't work, it just means that the `first` object within `resp` doesn't have the `findItemsByKeywordsResponse` key. You can `inspect` or print the parsed JSON response to see its full structure and to which keys it would respond.